# Hidden Div Tab-through (accessibility)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accessibility

I have a section where I have hidden divs that are being displayed on click. What I am trying to achieve is accessibility compliance where if I tab through and open one of the sections it will tab through the inner content of the section and then return to where it was left off initially.

Eg. If I tab through and open section 1 I would like to be able to tab through the inner contents of section 1 and after that go back to the button that opens up section 2, and so forth...

I have created a fiddle with my html / script
https://jsfiddle.net/rjvw915r/10/

HTML Example:

```
<div id="dropdown-menus">
  <div id="section1-drop" class="drop-section hidden-panel">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </div>

  <div id="section2-drop" class="drop-section hidden-panel">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </div>
</div>

<ul id="dropdown-links" class="menu main-tabs">
  <li>
    <a class="panel-btn" 
       href="javascript:dropMenu('section1');" 
       id="drop-link-section1">section 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="panel-btn" 
       href="javascript:dropMenu('section2');" 
       id="drop-link-section2">section 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
function dropMenu(menusection) {
    if ( !($('#dropdown-menus #' + menusection + '-drop').is(':hidden')) ) {

        // Select panel is open. Closes the panel.
        $('#dropdown-menus #' + menusection + '-drop').slideUp(500);
        $('#dropdown-menus #' + menusection + '-drop').removeClass('active');
        $('a#drop-link-' + menusection).removeClass('active');

        // Scroll to top of buttons.
        var aid = $("#dropdown-links");
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aid.offset().top-480},400,function(){});

    } else if ( $('#dropdown-menus .drop-section').hasClass('active') 
                && $('#dropdown-menus #' + menusection + '-drop').is(':hidden') ) {

        // Another panel is open. 
        // Closes currently open panel and opens selected panel.
        $('.menu a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('#dropdown-menus .active').slideUp(500,function(){
            $('#dropdown-menus #' + menusection + '-drop').slideDown(500);
            $('#dropdown-menus #' + menusection + '-drop').addClass('active');
            $('a#drop-link-' + menusection).addClass('active');
        }).removeClass('active');

        // Scroll to top of panel.
        var aid = $("#dropdown-menus");
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aid.offset().top-155},400,function(){});

    } else {

        // No panel currently open. Opens selected panel.
        $('#dropdown-menus #' + menusection + '-drop').slideDown(500);
        $('#dropdown-menus #' + menusection + '-drop').addClass('active');
        $('a#drop-link-' + menusection).addClass('active');

        // Scroll to top of panel.
        var aid = $("#dropdown-menus");
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aid.offset().top-155},400,function(){});
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I have added an abbreviated code example to your question. Please post future questions with the code in question, rather than just a fiddle link.

Comment: Sounds good, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `click` event to perform javascript actions when the link is clicked or enter is pressed.

```
<div id="dropdown-menus">
  <div id="section1-drop" class="drop-section hidden-panel">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </div>

  <div id="section2-drop" class="drop-section hidden-panel">
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  </div>
</div>

<ul id="dropdown-links" class="menu main-tabs">
  <li>
    <a class="panel-btn" 
       data-section="section1-drop"
       id="drop-link-section1">section 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="panel-btn" 
       data-section="section2-drop"
       id="drop-link-section2">section 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Above, I have removed the `href` attribute and added a `data-section` element which specifies which section this link activates. This is more semantic and readable, and now we can set up our handlers within jQuery.

Define the focus handler:

```
// Setup the focus handler for the root links
$('.panel-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    var link = $(this);
    var section = link.attr('data-section');

    // Pass in the current link and the section name to dropMenu
    dropMenu($(this), section);
});
```

I've cleaned up your drop menu function a bit to clarify what's happening

```
function dropMenu(link, menusection) {

  // Get the section specified by the menusection id
  var section = $('#' + menusection);

  // Get the open section by checking for the active class
  var openSection = $('#dropdown-menus').find('.drop-section.active');

  // Anonymous function for activating a section and focussing the 
  // first link within the section
  var showSection = function() {
    // Slide the section into view
    section.slideDown(500).addClass('active');

    // Focus the first link in the section.
    section.find('a').first().focus();
  }

  // If there is a section open, we want to slide it up first,
  // then call showSection when that has completed.

  if(openSection.length > 0) {

    // If the open section is the one that was clicked, we want
    // to simply close that section rather than open another
    if(openSecion[0] === section[0]) {
        openSection.slideUp(500).removeClass('active');
    }
    else {
        openSection.slideUp(500, showSection).removeClass('active');
    }
  }

  // Otherwise, we can just show the section straight away.
  else {
    showSection();
  }
}
```

This is all pretty standard, but the you now need to handle moving between sections as you would expect to happen natively using the tab key. The problem is that since your 'drop sections' are above the root links, tabbing from the last link in the drop section will always take you back to section 1 since that is the next tabbable element in the document. To prevent this, we need to work around some of the default functionality and implement our own.

First, you'll need to configure a `keydown` handler to catch the tabbing before it happens

```
// Setup a keydown handler to handle tabbing on section links
$('.drop-section').on('keydown', 'a', function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode === TAB_KEY) {
    var link = $(this);

    // Flag determins whether to prevent default tab behaviour
    var preventDef = false;

    // Travel to previous link on SHIFT + TAB
    if(e.shiftKey) {
      preventDef = travelPrevious(link);
    }

    // Travel to next link on TAB
    else {
      preventDef = travelNext(link);
    }

    // Prevent default focus behaviour
    if(preventDef) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```

Then we need functions to handle next tab, and previous tab

```
// Handles travelling to the next link
function travelNext(link) {
  var next = link.next();

  if(next.length > 0) {
    // Continue with default behaviour of moving to next link
    return false;
  }

  // Drop section parent ID
  var parentId = link.parents('.drop-section').attr('id');

  // Root link whose data-section attribute matches parent ID
  var rootLink = $('.panel-btn[data-section=' + parentId + ']').parent();

  // Next root link to move to.
  var nextLink = rootLink.next().find('a');

  // Focus on the next root link, which will fire dropMenu for 
  // the next section.
  nextLink.focus();

  // Prevent default behaviour
  return true;
}

function travelPrevious(link) {
  var prev = link.prev();

  if(prev.length > 0) {
    // Continue with default behaviour of moving to previous link
    return false;
  }

  // Drop section parent ID
  var parentId = link.parents('.drop-section').attr('id');

  // LI container for Root link whose data-section attribute matches parent ID
  var rootLink = $('.panel-btn[data-section=' + parentId + ']').parent();

  // Previous root link to move to.
  var prevLink = rootLink.prev().find('a');

  // Focus on the previous root link, which will fire dropMenu for 
  // the previous section.
  prevLink.focus();

  // Prevent default behaviour
  return true;
}
```

This is still not a complete solution because it will not handle reaching the end or beginning of all sections. It should be a start and I believe it answers your first question. If you other questions about this, you should ask them seperately.

Here is a fiddle example
https://jsfiddle.net/rjvw915r/17/

**UPDATE**

If your links are contained in a non-standard way within the drop-section, the method above won't quite work, as it uses the `next` and `prev` functions which look for direct siblings. If each `a` tag is contained in a `div` or `li` wrapper, then they have no direct siblings.

We can work around this by looking back to a known parent element, and finding all siblings via a selector. In the keydown function, we will add some additional code to retrieve these elements, and pass them into the travel functions.

```
$('.drop-section').on('keydown', 'a', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === TAB_KEY) {
        var link = $(this);

        // Retrieve all available links within the parent.
        var linkCollection = link.parents('.drop-section').find('a');

        ...
```

In each of the travel functions we pass these links in

```
preventDef = travelPrevious(link, linkCollection);

... 

preventDef = travelNext(link, linkCollection);
```

By finding the index of the current link, we can ascertain whether it has any siblings before or after it.

In the `travelNext` function we check to see if there are any links after it

```
// Find where the current link sits within the collection
var linkIndex = linkCollection.index(link);
var nextIndex = linkIndex + 1;

if(nextIndex < linkCollection.length) {
  // Continue with default behaviour of moving to next link.
  return false;
}
```

In the `travelPrevious` function we check to see if there are any links before it

```
// Find where the current link sits within the collection
var linkIndex = linkCollection.index(link);
var nextIndex = linkIndex - 1;

if(nextIndex >= 0) {
  // Continue with default behaviour of moving to previous link
  return false;
}
```

See updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rjvw915r/18/

Comment: This isn't quite what i'm looking for.

a) Section shouldn't open when tabbed over. Only on click / Enter.

b) The function now acts differently. It won't close the section if clicked on twice (if I click on a section to open and then again to close it will just slide up and down again).

I don't believe that I asked more than one question?

The main thing I need is to be able to tab inside the section when it is open.

I will play a bit what what you gave me and see if I can change a few things. If you have any additional suggestions based on this comment it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've updated the answer, you can use the click event to handle clicks and enter rather than the focus event. You can put a check inside the `dropMenu` function to determine whether the selected section is already open and just close it if it is. See the updated fiddle.

Comment: That is perfect! Thanks a million :)

Comment: While trying to apply this to the actual website I ran into another issue. If the drop sections content aren't just straight a tags it will skip them. So if I have an a inside of an li or another div it wont acknowledge it. See section 1 in the attached fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rjvw915r/18/   ---- Thoughts?

Comment: Seems to do the trick - but for some reason it says linkCollection is not defined when tabbing through the inner content. Did I do something wrong here? jsfiddle.net/rjvw915r/21

Comment: @danik Yes you need to add in the parameters to the function definitions. I didn't write that in the update, but since you are calling `travelNext(link, linkCollection)` you need to define it as such: `function travelNext(link, linkCollection)`.

Comment: Right, can't believe I didn't notice that. Works perfectly now. Thanks again for your help - you're a lifesaver :) Cheers!